# Use override of some methods of a contentPage in a ContentView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to use `ContentView` instead of a `ContentPage`, but before I had two overrides of the `OnAppearing()` and `OnBackButtonPressed()` methods. Is there any way I can use them anyway?

Comment: you would need to wire up the page events to call methods in the view

Comment: While this doesn't help you today, status of implementing life cycle events for views can be tracked in [Enhancement Add better life cycle events](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2210). In the meantime, there is [code](https://github.com/AlexPshul/XFLifecycle) that can help. Described in [Add life cycle events to views](https://www.pshul.com/2018/03/27/xamarin-forms-add-views-lifecycle-events/). Disclaimer: I have not used.

Comment: As i know, the ContentView  doesn't have the lifecycle event. You need to trigger it from a  Page.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT So is there a solution?

Comment: If you want to use life cycle, we suggest to use the ContentPage.